# Calling PHP Functions

Tags: php

Hi everyone, need a bit of help as I'm new to coding.

I have a movie site that is using Smarty template engine and what I want to do is to call this PHP function.

```
/* returns a list of category ids for the given movie */

public function getMovieCategories($movieid){
$movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
$e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_tags_join WHERE movie_id=$movieid") or die(mysql_error());
$tags = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($e)){
while($s = mysql_fetch_array($e)){
extract($s);
$tags[]=$tag_id;
}
}
return $tags;
}
```

To get and display the categories for each movie but I don't know how to do it, could some one please help Thanks.

Comment: `$categories=getMovieCategories(1); print_r($categories);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in your php code :-

```
$return_array = getMovieCategories($your_movie_id);
```

it wil call a function `getMovieCategories($movie_id)` and the result will be stored in `$return_array`

For more info please check this link - [Function Call](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)